# Nltk stanford pos tagger error : Java command failed

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, text-processing

I'm trying to use [`nltk.tag.stanford module`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford)  for tagging a sentence (first like wiki's example) but i keep getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    print st.tag(word_tokenize('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 59, in tag
    return self.tag_sents([tokens])[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.py", line 81, in tag_sents
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 160, in java
    raise OSError('Java command failed!')
OSError: Java command failed!
```

or following `LookupError` error :

```
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.
===========================================================================
```

this is the exapmle code :

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
>>> st = POSTagger('/usr/share/stanford-postagger/models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger',
...                '/usr/share/stanford-postagger/stanford-postagger.jar') 
>>> st.tag('What is the airspeed of an unladen swallow ?'.split())
```

I also used `word_tokenize` instead `split` but it doesn't made any difference.

I also installed java again or `jdk`! and my all searches were unsuccessful! something like `nltknltk.internals.config_java()` or ... !

Note : I use linux (Xubuntu)!

Answer (score 7):

If you read through the embedded documentation in the [nltk/internals.py](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/internals.py) (lines 58 - 175) you should find your answer easy enough. The NLTK requires the full path to the Java binary.

> If not specified, then nltk will search the system for a Java binary;
>   and if one is not found, it will raise a LookupError exception.

You have a couple of options I believe based on a bit of research:

**1) Add the following code to your project (not a great solution)**

```
import os
java_path = "path/to/java" # replace this
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
```

**2) Uninstall & Reinstall NLTK (preferably in a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) (better but still not great)**

```
pip uninstall nltk
sudo -E pip install nltk
```

**3) Set the java environment variable (This is the most pragmatic solution IMO)**

Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add following lines in end

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Comment: in `usr/lib/jvm/` i have 3 directory  `default-java` and `java-1.7.0-openjdak-amd64` and `java-7-openjdk-amd64` which one of them i may use for path ? i use all of them but i get the error again and try all of your way except `uninstall` and `install` nltk ! how you say i uninstall and install again ?

Comment: @Kasra java-1.7.0-openjdak-amd64 I believe

Comment: again in rewrite the code in a new `.py` file and executed it , then i get this error `print(stderr.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None` are you familiar with ? its for `nltk/internals.py` file !

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to replicate the issue now. Try java-7-openjdk-amd64 in the meantime and see if this works

Comment: What's the `$HOME` and `JRE_HOME` variables in your 3rd solution? They're not previously defined and just suddenly appear

Answer (score 1):

I've also run into this problem while using NLTK for the first time.
After some hours spent with this issue I finally managed to make it work.

That is what I did:

1. Uninstall and reinstall the nltk package
2. Add both the `JAVAHOME` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables variables (in my case, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\`)
3. Add the values (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\`) to the `Path` environment variable also.

And, naturally, restart your Terminal.

That worked for me at Windows 7 64-bit.