# Stanford tagger not working

Tags: java, python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I have tried using stanford pos tagger in nltk but it gives me error as:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
st = POSTagger('/.../models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger', '/.../stanford-postagger-full-2014-10-26/stanford-postagger.jar')
st.tag("dogs and cats".split())
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger : Unsupported major.minor
>   version 52.0
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 st.tag("love myself".split())
>
> /Users/bowang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.pyc
>   in tag(self, tokens)
>        57 
>        58     def tag(self, tokens):
>   ---> 59         return self.tag_sents([tokens])[0]
>        60 
>        61     def tag_sents(self, sentences):
>
> /Users/bowang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/stanford.pyc
>   in tag_sents(self, sentences)
>        79         # Run the tagger and get the output
>        80         stanpos_output, _stderr = java(self._cmd,classpath=self._stanford_jar,
>   ---> 81                                                        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>        82         stanpos_output = stanpos_output.decode(encoding)
>        83
>
> /Users/bowang/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/**init**.pyc
>   in java(cmd, classpath, stdin, stdout, stderr, blocking)
>       158     if p.returncode != 0:
>       159         print(stderr.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
>   --> 160         raise OSError('Java command failed!')
>       161 
>       162     return (stdout, stderr)
>
> OSError: Java command failed!

I have tried with what [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171298/nltk-stanford-pos-tagger-error-java-command-failed) answered (apart from uninstalling and reinstalling nltk) but still not working. Also I have tried running stanford-tagger.jar from the command line to process my data and it gives the same error, as:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTaggerGUI : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0

Has anyone had and solved this problem successfully before? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version of the Stanford Tagger requires Java 8. If you aren't able to upgrade, use an older version of the tagger.

Comment: Thanks so much! Apparently I only installed JRE 8 not JDK 8 and that's why in the system preferences it tells me Java is up to date but I couldn't find the new java under java_home...thanks again.

Comment: Version 3.5.0 and up requires Java 8. Latest version on Java 7 is 3.4.1. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml#History